# How to get snapcraft CLI on Arch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, packaging, snap

Following the instructions on https://snapcraft.io/docs/installing-snap-on-arch-linux, I've got a `snap` command on my computer. I can use the `snap` tool to login/etc, but I want to create a snap package - which requires running `snapcraft init`, which `snap` can't do.

How can I install the actual `snapcraft` tool on Arch Linux?

Answer (score 0):

Install `snapcraft` via snap: `sudo snap install snapcraft --classic`

Source: https://snapcraft.io/install/snapcraft/arch